# Need help identifying Hindu Goddess

Tags: identification-request, goddess, devi

Could someone please help me to identify the Goddess presented in the image?

[image]

But as you can see, She has two arms, and Her right hand is raised as if She is offering a blessing. Please tell me who She is.

Comment: Appears like Radha. Could be iskcon Deity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She is [Radharani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radha), Shakthi of Sri Krishna. This image could be taken from ISKCON.

Another similar image of Radha and Krishna from [ISKCON London](https://www.triphobo.com/places/london-united-kingdom/iskcon-london-radha-krishna-temple).

[image]

Another similar *alankara* of Radha Krishna can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/Lo5XQLY7yGw?t=74) which is from ISKCON Chennai.